# Moving a domain

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

Hi I am hoping for some advice.

I have just managed to get a .co domain so I wish to point all requests from my .co.nz domain to the .co 
I am running IIS7.5 
I have created a services site e.g. services.mydomain.co.nz and the website mydomain.co.nz both are running on their own website and app pool.

At the moment I don't want to break any of the web services so I want to keep the services site as services.mydomain.co.nz but I want to automatically redirect website users to the .co domain instead of .co.nz

So far I have added a new host header in IIS and this allows me to hit the website using the .co domain but I can still hit the site using .co.nz

Do I need to create a url rewrite function to help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http redirection in IIS to direct all requests at the old domain to exactly the same path at the new domain.

You want to choose options as I have in this photo:

[image: HTTP Redirect]

Include the full base url to the new site, ending at the slash after the domain name. then leave the other options as I have them; this way, any request at the old domain will be sent a 301 "permanent" code to redirect to the new, equivalent page on the new site.

Note that it's important that you do *not* check the first of those checkboxes under 'Redirect Behavior'; that will make it send all requests to the home page of your site, rather than to the same path url.

This should be on a separate IIS site, by the way.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Just so I am clear, I create a new site and copy over my current website into its folder, I then setup the above on the old site?

Comment: Correct; the above would be on the old site. Be sure to vote up/check as 'Accepted' answer if this works!